# Struggling with inversion

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

- (The guy that was fired) - For what he was responsible?
- (The guy that was fired) - For what was he responsible?
- (The guy that was fired) - What for he was responsible?
- (The guy that was fired) - What for was he responsible?

Which one is correct?

Comment: In order to answer this question, we need more information. Please include the context the sentence will be used in and the research you have done to try to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern spoken English, most people would say this:

> What was he responsible for?

There is really not much to explain. You just need to learn the pattern. Here's how it works:

> what + helping verb or the verb to be + subject + main verb (optionally) + preposition?

Example #1:

> **What** are you looking at me like that **for**? What did I do?

Example #2:

> **What** are you arresting him **for**? He didn't do anything wrong!

Example #3:

> **What user name** are you currently logged in **under**?

Comment: In formal or written English, some people would prefer "For what was he responsible?" But in any case, "for" must either precede "what" or come at the end; and where a question begins with a WH-word that is not the subject, the subject always follows the verb.